# MySQL: Is there a way to automatically set datetime field to record creation timestamp?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I know there is TIMESTAMP data type that automatically updates to timestamp value when a record is updated, and I already have such column.

Besides that I'd like to have a column that automatically populates to NOW() (or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and never changes, but MySQL DEFAULT doesn't appear to support function calls.

Please post only pure MySQL answers. I know how to do it at application level.

EDIT: If there's no such feature - I'd appreciate to hear that.

EDIT2: MySQL version is 5.0.32

Comment: OK. My bad. I forgot to mention that I'd like to use REPLACE INTO, and that's why I want that to happen 'automatically' - without being explicit about that.

Comment: you can, **BUT** only one `default current_timestamp` allowed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a trigger to set the default.

> ```
> DELIMITER |
>
> CREATE
>     TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_name FOR EACH ROW 
> BEGIN
>     SET NEW.colname = NOW();
> END;
> ```
>
> |

Try this one, including the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'll accept it. Btw, PHPMyAdmin will have problem with this statement, because of ";" that's used as a statement delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to have a column that automatically populates to NOW() (or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and never changes

By saying you'd like it to *populate* to NOW() it sounds like you're referring to the initial `INSERT`. If that's the case, can you just use that? Something like

```
INSERT INTO table (field1,field2,my_datetime) VALUES (1,'a',NOW())
```

Comment: Exactly. Only this is not quite automatic... I'd like to never mention that column in INSERT statements.

Comment: Now way I know of then -- I'd lean towards the trigger.

Comment: I guess I'll accept trigger. However, I'm stuck with this MySQL version, and creating a trigger requires SUPER privilege, so it doesn't really work for me :(

Comment: You need TRIGGER privileges: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_trigger